# How to get 'Current usage percentage' for CPU's via Service Usage API

Tags: google-cloud-platform

On the quotas page, there are a few things listed for different Quotas.

I am focusing on CPU's Quota. I can get the Dimensions and the Effective Limit. But could not find anything in the API for getting 'Current usage percentage'.

Basically, I need to know what is my current CPU's usage for a specific region.

Help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm not exactly what you're asking about - can you clarify your question ? If we're talking about number of CPU's available for you then it's visible in [quotas page for your project](https://console.cloud.google.com/iam-admin/quotas) - you can see the actual number and current percantage usage.

Comment: I think you haven't API to get the current quota usage, only to know/update the limits

Comment: @Wojtek_B
I want to call API and calculate how much quota is left for me. Meaning, limit - used quota.

Comment: So - the value I mentioned is the one you want - it's just you want to get it via API - correct ?

Comment: @Wojtek_B yes. If I look at the GO API, I can do serviceusage.QuotaBucket.EffectiveLimit which give me the limit. I would like to see how much is used. If you look at the console it's the 'Current usage percentage' column name in the Quota page. serviceusage.QuotaBucket object, doe snot have it.

Answer (score 1):

There is a way of getting the actual number of resources used in a certain region by using a `serviceruntime.googleapis.com/quota/allocation/usage` [metric](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/resources#tag_consumer_quota).

It won't give you a percentage but a number of VM's, CPU's etc.

Have a look at my [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71674245/12257250) to a very similar question describing how it's done.

In essence you need to use a metric I mentioned and then you can call the Cloud Monitoring API to get the number (let's call it "x"). You still need to get the actual quota value (lets call it "y") and calculate x/y and then you will get a percentage.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the response. I get the following error ``` <p>The requested URL <code>/v1beta1/projects/912272401495/serviceruntime.googleapis.com/quota/allocation/usage?alt=json&amp;prettyPrint=false</code> was not found on this server.  <ins>That’s all we know.</ins>```.  The GO code is: ```client.serviceUsageService.Services.ConsumerQuotaMetrics.Get("projects/" +
  strconv.Itoa(int(projectNumber)) + "/serviceruntime.googleapis.com/quota/allocation/usage".Do()'''

Comment: Which service should I use, to call this metric?

Comment: Did you create a proper metric with MQL query that will get the value you want ?

Comment: I wrote "fetch consumer_quota
| metric 'serviceruntime.googleapis.com/quota/allocation/usage'
| filter
(resource.service == 'compute.googleapis.com') && (metric.quota_metric == 'compute.googleapis.com/cpus') | group_by 32401s, [value_usage : max(value.usage)]" and I get max vCPU's but not the current one.  Even whene changing the number '32401' to different values. Did not help. Keep getting wrong number of cpus count.

Comment: Hi @Wojtek_B, you must help me here.... I'm almost there. Any idea how to tweak this query to get the exact value? I tried to add the 'within' attribute. Did not help much

Comment: Last query is 'fetch consumer_quota
| metric 'serviceruntime.googleapis.com/quota/allocation/usage' 
| filter (resource.service == 'compute.googleapis.com') && (metric.quota_metric == 'compute.googleapis.com/cpus')
| group_by 1m, [value_usage : max(value.usage)]
| within d'2022/04/16-19:15:00', d'2022/04/17-19:15:00'

Comment: I've been trying to get some reasonable number out of this metric but also with no success. I believe there may be another metric - or - if this one doesn't do the job right you may raise a feature request on [Google's IssueTracker](https://issuetracker.google.com).