# How to get GCP Quota limits for virtual machine using token based access

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, quota

I want to get the GCP VM limits using token based access.
Below is my python code.

```
from googleapiclient import discovery
from oauth2client import AccessTokenCredentials
import httplib2

token = 'xyz'
credentials = AccessTokenCredentails(access_token=token, user_agent='MyAgent')
http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
service = discovery.build('serviceusage', 'v1', http=http)
#...
# code to get the GCP Quota for VM.
```

I have to get the quota before creating the VMs before running terraform to create resources to make sure the number of instances are available.

Comment: Have you tried to get quota usage data using the [Cloud Monitoring API](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/docs/apis) and the [`consumer_quota`](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/resources#tag_consumer_quota) resource ?

Answer (score 3):

To get a value about the actual resource's usage you can use a [Cloud Monitoring API](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/docs/apis) and the [consumer_quota](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/resources#tag_consumer_quota) resource. It's not going to be a percentage but actual value.

For example:

You want to know how many VM's there's in `us-central1`

There's a [metric](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/resources#tag_consumer_quota) for that: `serviceruntime.googleapis.com/quota/allocation/usage`. It provides with actual usage.

Then you can [create a MQL](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/mql/query-editor) query to filter everything you need:

```
fetch consumer_quota
| metric 'serviceruntime.googleapis.com/quota/allocation/usage'
| filter
    (resource.service == 'compute.googleapis.com')
    && (metric.quota_metric == 'compute.googleapis.com/instances')
| group_by 1d, [value_usage_aggregate: aggregate(value.usage)]
| every 1d
```

Now - when you [run this through API with curl](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/mql/qn-from-api#ql-timeseries-query):

```
curl -d @query.json -H "Authorization: Bearer $TOKEN" \
--header "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST \
https://monitoring.googleapis.com/v3/projects/${PROJECT_ID}/timeSeries:query
```

you will get a response:

```
{
  "timeSeriesDescriptor": {
    "labelDescriptors": [
      {
        "key": "resource.project_id"
      },
      {
        "key": "resource.service"
      },
      {
        "key": "resource.location"
      },
      {
        "key": "metric.quota_metric"
      }
    ],
    "pointDescriptors": [
      {
        "key": "value_usage_aggregate",
        "valueType": "INT64",
        "metricKind": "GAUGE",
        "unit": "1"
      }
    ]
  },
  "timeSeriesData": [
    {
      "labelValues": [
        {
          "stringValue": "my-test-project"
        },
        {
          "stringValue": "compute.googleapis.com"
        },
        {
          "stringValue": "us-central1"
        },
        {
          "stringValue": "compute.googleapis.com/instances"
        }
      ],
      "pointData": [
        {
          "values": [
            {
              "int64Value": "11"
            }
          ],
          "timeInterval": {
            "startTime": "2022-03-30T08:38:44.064174Z",
            "endTime": "2022-03-30T08:38:44.064174Z"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Line that interests you is  `"int64Value": "11"` that contains number  11 which in my case is the current number or VM's (it's a sum of both running and stoped).

Now "all" you need to do is to incorporate that into your python script.

Comment: I'm currently using service.regions().get(project_id="pid",  region="xyz").execute().